# Find the highest object in array tree of nested children

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, find

I have an array of nested regions that look like this:

- Egypt

  - Zone 1

    - Tagamo3
    - Giza
    - Helwan
    - Fayoum
  - Zone 2

    - Gesr ElSuis

      - test
    - Delta
    - Mohandeseen
    - Down Town

The array itself:

```js
[
  {
    "key": 10,
    "title": "Egypt",
    "parent_key": null,
    "children": [
      {
        "key": 1,
        "title": "Zone 1",
        "parent_key": 10,
        "children": [
          {
            "key": 3,
            "title": "Tagamo3",
            "parent_key": 1,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "key": 7,
            "title": "Giza",
            "parent_key": 1,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "key": 8,
            "title": "Helwan",
            "parent_key": 1,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "key": 11,
            "title": "Fayoum",
            "parent_key": 1,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": 2,
        "title": "Zone 2",
        "parent_key": 10,
        "children": [
          {
            "key": 4,
            "title": "Gesr ElSuis",
            "parent_key": 2,
            "children": [
              {
                "key": 12,
                "title": "test",
                "parent_key": 4,
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "key": 5,
            "title": "Delta",
            "parent_key": 2,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "key": 6,
            "title": "Mohandeseen",
            "parent_key": 2,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "key": 9,
            "title": "Down Town",
            "parent_key": 2,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to return to the highest region in a given input

**Examples:**

- input [7, 1, 10] should return [10] since 10 is **Egypt** parent of 1 and 7
- input [1, 2] should return both [1, 2] since they are on the same level both **Zone 1** and **zone 2** located under **Egypt**
- input [2, 3, 1] should return [2, 1] since they are on the same level and 3 removed because it's a child of 1
- input [1, 4] should return [1, 4] since they are on different levels and no one parent to the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First it helps to turn your tree structure into a map of descendant ids, recursively:

```
const descendantsMap = new Map<number, Set<number>>();
function walk(tree: Tree) {
  const s: Set<number> = new Set();
  descendantsMap.set(tree.key, s);
  for (const t of tree.children) {
    walk(t);
    s.add(t.key);
    descendantsMap.get(t.key)?.forEach(v => s.add(v));
  }
}
arr.forEach(walk);
```

We are building up [a `Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) from each `key` in your tree structure to [a `Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of the `key`s of its descendants.  The `walk()` function is recursive, and we merge the descendants for the `children` of each node into the descendants for the current node.

Let's make sure it looks right:

```
console.log(descendantsMap);
/* Map (12) {
    10 => Set (11) {1, 3, 7, 8, 11, 2, 4, 12, 5, 6, 9}, 
    1 => Set (4) {3, 7, 8, 11}, 
    3 => Set (0) {}, 
    7 => Set (0) {}, 
    8 => Set (0) {}, 
    11 => Set (0) {}, 
    2 => Set (5) {4, 12, 5, 6, 9}, 
    4 => Set (1) {12}, 
    12 => Set (0) {}, 
    5 => Set (0) {}, 
    6 => Set (0) {}, 
    9 => Set (0) {}
} */
```

Yes. You can see how now we have a quick mapping from each `key` to the set of `key`s in its descendant subtree.

---

Now to get the "highest" entries in an array (I would call these the "shallowest" since they are closest to the root), we find all the descendants of all the elements in the array and then filter these out of the array:

```
const shallowest = (x: number[]): number[] => {
  const descendants = new Set<number>();
  for (const v of x) {
    descendantsMap.get(v)?.forEach(i => descendants.add(i));
  }
  console.log(descendants); // just to understand what's happening
  return x.filter(v => !descendants.has(v));
}
```

Let's test it:

```
console.log(shallowest([7, 1, 10])); 
// descendants are {3, 7, 8, 11, 1, 2, 4, 12, 5, 6, 9} 
// output [10]

console.log(shallowest([1, 2])); 
// descendants are {3, 7, 8, 11, 4, 12, 5, 6, 9};
// output [1, 2]

console.log(shallowest([2, 3, 1])); 
// descendants are {4, 12, 5, 6, 9, 3, 7, 8, 11};
// output [2, 1]

console.log(shallowest([1, 4])); 
// descendants are {3, 7, 8, 11, 12};
// output [1, 4]
```

Looks good. You can see that `shallowest([7, 1, 10])` first finds all the descendants of `7`, `1`, and `10`, which is `{3, 7, 8, 11, 1, 2, 4, 12, 5, 6, 9}`, or everything *except* `10`.  So when we filter those out of `[7, 1, 10]` we are left with just `10`.  Similarly, `shallowest([1, 2])` and `shallowest([1, 4])` produce sets of descendants that don't overlap at all with the input, so the output is identical to the input.  And with `shallowest([2, 3, 1])`, the list of descendants contains `3` but not `2` or `1`, so the output is `[2, 1]`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=4.7.4#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-3uoPS0N4cMiz1RkNh23x2WJzgx3BxkUC9PGnIG71G01IC1Ia0pkV69NyvCC7NXQXpzMN5rG5vJv3xs0d2OVq6W3tZrFITnsuT5JQqKBbTA0yzQFRmTgADwEFUCkik64CbkkktyzUWKgZTM6NQs1jK-kqwUadrB82PSDhKyQK+FItPHS+PT+VFhYF8QhKFOBoSVv2ZW57jA1EmgxO0RCoMhmEYFdQV2Kg3FhSUAEJIM6bpZy4FE2SQTFySUSlqVpTgZznOgF2UTgxA9BVvTFaQIiQdl2SQMRxQkSjCmo7oaTpeiMHnRcWPYgUuPCHi+IEnUhLyCkqTE2jJOk5ixCNN0+QUpT+KNIzhKgUTxLo2cpMYmSVKQPVjN4-j2OcicKMIbyohoXQ3BIBBkCyZBDwUHY9gOTJ0kkdxjmGEYd1vKJsSQZ9cRqMRjjC+QACIEtygRxTiq5ctoKgqUKpBcvBH4RhgKhcpK5pcrgA4qAAfQKncpOavJcu2XZ9kZKqsvjHLSu670+pFMqaAqiAqtygAtBhkD5JqI2IVqeEZTqpuKrbqsGyKRoEMb43kCbLvy0YquVI7+vKyqBFywQQB+cA6EVTbLpatq9q6u6ipmv6Boi4bgFGtS-vI0GRWu+NbpGKq1UevLnsW16AHEaCwEBfth7aAd0IGUZB9HtpOyHofRm10cR2aps1SnqsxpaAAkIAwRIofhpGSf24HptZ8GhoOWmifponGcm4XtVF9nXoAMRAEY6CcQmiZ29qyaqhVRepiXzphv7UvjU2MX52Qwam3UjrmhaltWiwkAFLXZsFvWirFa2qYh43+IZ0WpoNRX5pe6rsegOZwQwLwyBoKAPbBr27b9lqjbOoOibyWWboO+3c5apW2cXFPc51wHQ4zpGs6hk3WeIc3Yct+Npdh-P+qm01w6d16ABFuaoAna7ytPhaLyv68l2GO7+ru8qmi0+8j3L9DoWctGgUQ+dFifybdsf-fF7PJDpsfF+2qbLWPtmI6x6qB8YxhBBfiuBd20n08NgOz7bkULcrgAObnaS2qUJDwRYGwaAXBcSTHREAA)

Answer (score 0):

This is my 2nd attempt, thanks to jcalz for pointing out the error and his solution is neater than mine.

The function buildArray builds an array of objects in to the variable keyArray, the key is the element in the array to be searched and another array that's the path to that element (so key 7 will have a path of [10, 1, 7]).

We then filter keyArray to remove any elements that have a parent in the original search array.

Anyway, reading jcalz's solution, I've learnt about maps so my time's not been entirely wasted. Hope this helps in some way though.

```
console.log(search2([7, 1, 10], obj));  //returns [10]
console.log(search2([1,2], obj));       //returns [1,2]
console.log(search2([2,3,1], obj));     //returns [1,2]
console.log(search2([1,4], obj));       //returns [1,4]

function search2(search, obj) {
  keyArray=[];
  buildArray(obj);
  return keyArray.filter((element)=> !element.path.some(e => search.includes(e))).map((e)=> e.key);
  
  function buildArray(obj, path=[]) {
    obj.forEach((element) =>{
      if(search.includes(element.key)) {
        keyArray.push({"key":element.key,"path":path});
      }
      buildArray(element.children,[...path,element.key]);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like this returns the `[1, 4]` output for a `[1, 4]` input.

Comment: You're correct. I think I've misunderstood that one. I'll have a think 